# 2-dimensional formatting for integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, formatting, integral-equations

So I am trying to integrate the function `x^2 * Sin^2[n Pi x / a], {x,0,a}`.
The code I am using is in the "two-dimensional formatting" of mathematica: I am using Esc [] Esc to use the actual integral sign and differential. For example, Esc int Esc gives the integral sign and Esc dd Esc gives the differential. However, whenever I press Shift+Enter, it gives an error. Here is the code when copying the formatting shown in the photo:
`Subscript[\[Integral], 0]^a[x^2* Sin[n Pi x/a]^2] \[DifferentialD]x`

How am I supposed to integrate this way?

[image: formatting shown]

Comment: Esc int Esc x^2 * Sin[n * Pi * x/a]^2 Esc dd Esc x Shift Enter  (I think your use of [ and ] around your whole expression was the problem, those mean completely different things to Mathematica than ( and ) mean.

Comment: i.e. the square brackets are causing the issue. Your code will run correctly if you delete them.

Comment: The use of `Superscript` and `Subscript` described under "Details and  Options" of the `Integrate` documentation appears to be wrong.  Instead, follow the fourth example under "Basic Examples" to insert limits on the integral, which works fine (with the outer square brackets removed, of course).

Comment: That isn't the problem. I take them off and error still occurs. I will try that @bbgodfrey, thanks

Comment: @bbgodfrey, that did the trick. It was the upper limit. I used a super script, the correct keys were "Ctrl + %" Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I was sloppy in my comment.  "Details and Options" of the Integrate documentation says, enter integration limits as subscript and superscript.  Apparently, the way to enter them is not with `Subscript` and `Superscript` but rather by the means shown in the fourth example under "Basic Examples".  Glad it worked for you.

Comment: They should really change that, but I suppose. Thanks again. @bbgodfrey

Comment: Try to use `Esc+dintt+Esc ` which will give you the sign of the integral with the slots for the limits. In addition the code `x^2 * Sin^2[n Pi x / a]` is a syntax error. You need to give it as follows: `x^2 * Sin[n Pi x / a]^2`. Have fun!